# Is there any way to make stairs which NPCs can choose whether or not to climb?

Tags: terraria

So far all I've seen is stairs which NPCs climb when they reach them, or stairs where they walk right past the bottom of them. Is there any way to build stairs where they can either climb them *or* walk past them? I'd like to have my NPCs be able to go hang out together during the day, but still be able to get back to their houses at night.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.2.3, platforms in the sloped position will become stairs:

[image]

You can get platforms into the sloped position by hitting them with a hammer

These stairs will allow the NPC's to walk up them or past them.

Comment: I think you might be referring to the effect hammer has on front items, where it changes the graphic, but im not sure. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Timelord64 yes. What do you mean by "front items"

Comment: Anything that does not go in the back, like a wall does

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway. This answer was flagged as low quality but I see you've made some improvements so I expect it won't get flagged again

Comment: @Timelord64 ah okay, hammering items doesn't just change the graphic, differently positioned stuff has different properties too

Comment: I've never seen NPCs walk past stairs. In your picture, they can walk through them from the left, but from the right they will always go up the stairs

Comment: @SaintWacko really? I'll test this when I can, I thought that it would work, the other ways would be to make (any) stairs on the side of the house with a platform on top, or to use wiring on side stairs, or you can simply try leaving a gap, say in this picture destroy the lowermost platform, because they can jump if they wish to go up otherwise if they walk normally they won't even hit a platform. I'll get back to this question in a couple of days when I can test it.

Comment: If you remove the bottom platform of the stairs, they can walk down the stairs, but they won't walk back up it. I've been trying to figure out some way to use actuators on the stairs, but I can't think of a way to toggle them to allow the proper NPCs to use the stairs. I think the real problem is not with the stairs, but with the NPC AI. Instead of pathfinding to their room, they just head in the horizontal direction. Hopefully that is changed in Otherworld.

Comment: @SaintWacko yes then the problem is definitely with the AI, because they most definitely CAN jump up one block, it seems they just don't feel like it.

Comment: @SaintWacko in this case I don't think it's possible to fulfill all your requirements. Is allowing 2nd+ level occupants to return to ground level adequate?

Comment: I suppose I'll have to accept that. I already have that working, but it looks like that's the best I'll get